# Tkinter Python frame.pack() command Not Giving The Expected Output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I've been following a **Tkinter Python** [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/#working-with-widgets) on its *frame widget*.
(Under the subsection **Assigning Widgets to Frames With Frame Widgets**. Search by that phrase to get there easily.)

```
frame_a=tk.Frame()    
frame_b=tk.Frame()

label_a=tk.Label(text="I am frame A")   
label_a.master=frame_a    
label_a.pack()   

label_b=tk.Label(text="I am frame B")  
label_b.master=frame_b
label_b.pack()

frame_a.pack()  
frame_b.pack()
```

When I ran this code it successfully gave [image: this] output.
Consider the last two lines; the tutorial suggested to change their order, and put `frame_b.pack()` before `frame_a.pack()` and that will make the phrase **'I am frame B'** will come on top, as *frame_b* is packed first.

However, I get the same output as before. What is am I doing wrong here? (The code runs without errors.)

Comment: Give your frames a width and height, and a distinctive color. That will make it easier for you to see what is happening. Setting the `master` attribute like you're doing does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1):

As @Brian commented, label_a.master() does not do anything, so move the label.pack() commands like this:

```
frame_a=tk.Frame()    
frame_b=tk.Frame()

label_a=tk.Label(text="I am frame A")   

label_b=tk.Label(text="I am frame B")  

label_b.pack()
label_a.pack()#Moved

frame_b.pack()
frame_a.pack()
```